# Draw to Android screen through API

Tags: android, screen, display

guys.
I need some application on Android with API, that allows draw picture on screen and send touches (and other input) from Android.

For example, I connect from my C# app to Android app and use it as external screen.
Prefered through ip, but USB is also ok.

Thank you.

I try google some app for this but without success

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.